# Partition key predicate must include all partition key columns

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to create query in spark using scala language, the data is available in cassandra database as a table. In Cassandra table i have two keys, 1) Primary Key
2) Partition Key

Cassandra DDL will be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A.B (
    id1 text,
    id2 text,
    timing timestamp,
    value float,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id1, id2), timing)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timing DESC)
```

My Spark Programming:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","192.168.xx.xxx").set("spark.cassandra.auth.username","test").set("spark.cassandra.auth.password","test")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
var ctable = sc.cassandraTable("A", "B").select("id1","id2","timing","value").where("id1=?","1001")
```

When i query the same for "value" I'm obtaining the result, but when i query for id1 or id2 i'm receiving an error.

Error Obtained:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Partition key predicate must include all partition key columns or partition key columns need to be indexed. Missing columns: id2

I'm Using spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7, Cassandra 3.9, scala 2.11.8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Output i required was obtained by using following program.

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","192.168.xx.xxx").set("spark.cassandra.auth.username","test").set("spark.cassandra.auth.password","test")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
var ctable = sc.cassandraTable("A", "B").select("id1","id2","timing","value").where("id1=?","1001").where("id2=?","1002")
```

This is how we can access to partition key in cassandra database through Spark.